# How to understand out of bound in the following theoretical context?

Tags: loop-invariants

Consider the following initialization step of loop invariant for merge procedure

**Initialization**: Prior to the first iteration of the loop, **we have 
$k=p$, so that the subarray $A[p .. k - 1]$ is empty**. This empty subarray contains the k- p= 0 smallest elements of $L$ and $R$, and since 
$i = j = 1$, both $L[i]$ and $R[j]$ are the smallest elements of their arrays that have not been copied back into  $A$.

I have doubt in the above statement that if $k=p$, then array $A[p..p-1]$ is impossible and hence the further argument cannot proceed, which didn't happen. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with empty subarrays, especially if they have length exactly zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often useful to allow arrays of zero length. These are just empty arrays. The length of the subarray $A[i\ldots j]$ is $j-i+1$, so when $j=i-1$, we just get an array of length 0.

Why is this useful? Here are some examples:

- An array $A[1\ldots n]$ can always be partitioned into two arrays $A[1\ldots i]$ and $A[i+1 \ldots n]$ of lengths $i,n-i$. This works even for $i \in \{0,n\}$.
- We can construct an array $A[1\ldots n]$ inductively using the formula $A[1\ldots i] = A[1\ldots (i-1)] \cdot A[i]$. The base case is the empty array $A[1\ldots 0]$.

Having arrays of *negative* length makes less sense, and could lead to confusion and errors, since there is no semantics under which the formula $|A[i\ldots j]| = j-i+1$ would hold for them, since array lengths are non-negative.